# Eclipse tool for automatically deciding which unit tests are possibly affected by a source change

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

I have a large Java project in Eclipse with multiple modules and unit tests that may take long, so running all of them is impractical.

I would like a tool that decides which unit tests are actually possibly affected by a source change and runs only those.

This decision would be based on the imports: a test importing a class that was modified, or which itself uses some other class that has been modified, and so on, must be run.

Is there such a tool available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/infinitest may be the plugin you want. It continually runs tests for units you changed and shows feedback as a small green or red field in the status bar.

On a sidenote: unit tests do not have external dependencies and thus usually should not run too long. If you have tests that run very long, that may be a hint on them not being unit tests. You should separate those from the unit tests, for example by tagging and filtering them: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering